# Switch in front of router - multiple public IPs

Tags: networking, router, switch, datacenter

Network Gurus,

This seems logical and doable but want to have an advice from experts. We have /26 on single drop in our datacenter.

Some of our application servers (A) need public IP addresses and hence the need for these many addresses. Those servers in old setup [ Router -> Managed Switch (vlans)-> individual lan switches/vlans] were on separate vlan and we had dedidcated /24 drop by datacenter provider connected to the managed switch just for that. Also main applications (B) were behind FW that had separate drop of /27 and lan port was serving off our needs (lan port was also switched through same managed switch on private vlan).

We are moving datacenter and this time, rather than going for two drop solution, I was thinking of either having basic dumb switch/hub in front of router or managed switch in front of router. Router / FW would serve our main applications (B), where as other application servers that need to be on public facing IP feed from the same switch. What solution would be better ?

Also another alternative is that our router has dmz port as well and multi 1:1 NAT capability. I could create virtual interface on WAN port with sub range of IPs natted 1:1 to the dmz local IP range. In that situation, will I have to create policy route (SNAT) for those servers to go out ?

Thanks

Purvesh

Comment: A few comments. It is good that you mentioned how you did your current setup in order to provide some context. Of course I wouldn't necessarily base the new setup directly on the old setup, because any changes in the setup might as well be done as part of the move. So what I would first look for in deciding how the new setup will look is what the requirements are. Unfortunately it is not very clear from your question what your requirements are.

Comment: How many hosts do you have? How many do you expect to grow to in the near future? How many public IP addresses do you need? What do you need them for? You mention that some of the hosts do not need public IP addresses, what does those hosts need to communicate with then?

Comment: One recommendation: Make sure that the new data center has IPv6. It would be silly to move into a data center now and in a year or two have to move again because you realize that you need IPv6 and the data center still doesn't have it.

Comment: Hi Kasper ... data center is geared for ipv6 though we are not yet :-) ... We are going to have quite a few. Currently we have roughly 40ish hosts that need public IP. Hosts with private IPs are where our core servers are, need very few public IPs for them as they are behind proxy that does port translation and further they are also being served off virtual server within the router.

Answer (score 3):

Whether to use a router or a switch at a service provider's edge is typically dictated by the manner in which the IP range will be delivered to you.

An address range which the provider gives you with an "upstream gateway", and no routing configuration at your end has to have a layer two connection to the gateway (or simulated as such; cf Proxy ARP) in order for the packets to flow.  When a packet gets to the upstream router, it assumes that the destination address is on the local L2 segment, and will just ARP away for it.  That means you need to have a switch (or other L2 network) for all of the consumers of the address space.  That doesn't mean everything *has* to be directly connected, though -- if you place a router at your end and run Proxy ARP on it, you can still do L3 filtering (firewalling) on the traffic before it gets to the destination; you just have a more complicated and hard to debug network environment.

Since that can be quite an undertaking for a larger netblock, it only tends to happen for smaller blocks, or providers who don't know what they're doing.  At the big end of town, you'll typically get a very small range (or even a point-to-point link) between the service provider's router and yours, and all additional netblocks will be routed to your router *via* that address.

For instance, if you've been assigned `192.0.2.0/25` as your big-chunk-of-IP-addresses, you'd also be given a smaller allocation (say `192.0.2.192/29`) and be told, "the upstream gateway is `192.0.2.193`.  You then configure your routers (HA pair, natch) to have IP addresses `192.0.2.194` and `192.0.2.195`, and configure `192.0.2.196` as the HA IP that one router of the pair will have "control" of at any given moment.  You then tell the service provider, "please route my big-block-of-IPs to `192.0.2.196`, and then either router can handle the traffic, depending on which one has the speaking stick at the time.

An additional useful benefit of this approach is that multiple blocks can be routed to the same IP, reducing the hassle factor of lots of fiddly network configs over the same L2 segment.  You *also* don't have to waste the first and last addresses of the block on network and broadcast addresses, because you're not actually "subnetting" in that sense, merely routing chunks of address space.

Comment: Hi Womble, Thanks for the detailed explanation and btw sorry for late reply as was away during thanks giving break. We got full range of IP as part of same subnet and not as what you suggested as a ideal way. In old datacenter, that was exactly the setup, we got small block and large block. Though we got the second large block on dedicated separate drop. In this situation, am trying to avoid going for two drop solution.  So going by your reasoning - theoretically I should be able to do this ... : ISP<-> Our SW, Our Router <-> SW serving off public facing Servers,  .. contd ...

Comment: Router serving small chunk if it is configured such a way  since bigger chunk devices will be switched by switch and they should see ISP's gateway directly. Down side is that I will not be able to access these servers from my LAN as there will be no route information - packets will travel to the edge and come back. Is this correct understanding ?

Answer (score 0):

To the interested,

The solution I took was simpler and better. Rather than putting switch in front of the router and splitting the network there or having separate drop, I decided to go with SNAT routing option. Our router does support multi 1:1 NAT, had to configure SNAT policy (policy routes) that substitutes inside IP to outside IP. The biggest benefit of this is that servers are behind firewall rather than DMZ. Only downside to this approach was to firewall these servers such that they cannot access any resources within LAN. We opened just the necessary ports from WAN IPs to these servers, and having blocked all access from these servers to lan servers, effectively we created tight secure system that gives benefit of DMZ yet security of firewall.